# facebook user me python

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am using the Facebook python sdk to get the user's email

```
import facebook as facebooksd
cookie = facebooksd.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies, 
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
graph = facebooksd.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
current_user = graph.get_object("me")
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error with the code above:

```
global name 'self' is not defined
```

How do I get the cookies from Facebook to plug into the facebooksd.get_user_from_cookie function above? Thanks!

Comment: To plug into *what* function above? I don't see you defining any function. If you can provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), that might help.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explaining or not? self is not defined, because you're using it outside any class structure. Rather can copy-pasting some code you should look into the api what object this function requires and where you can use the function

Comment: Which Python GraphAPI wrapper are you using? http://www.pythonforfacebook.com, or one of the four others?

Comment: Also, please post the entire traceback, not just the error message. It's almost certain that the exception is coming from the second line, where you're using a non-existent `self`. But rather than making us guess that, you could have just posted the traceback that explicitly says that, or read it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course without the actual traceback, and a runnable sample, it's difficult to be positive. But your problem almost certainly happens before you even get into any Facebook code, in the middle of your second line:

```
import facebook as facebooksd
cookie = facebooksd.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies, 
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
```

You can split that second line up into pieces:

```
import facebook as facebooksd
cookies = self.request.cookies
cookie = facebooksd.get_user_from_cookie(cookies, 
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
```

And even move the second line to the top:

```
cookies = self.request.cookies
import facebook as facebooksd
cookie = facebooksd.get_user_from_cookie(cookies, 
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
```

And remove everything else:

```
cookies = self.request.cookies
```

And voila, same error, without any Facebook code.

You're trying to access a global variable named `self`, and there is no such variable. Exactly as the error message said.

So, how do you fix this? Well, that depends. What did you *expect* `self.request.cookies` to be? Where is it supposed to come from? If you copied and pasted this from some other code (where presumably it's part of a method on some object, where `self` refers to that object), you have to do whatever that code does to get the cookies.

Comment: Good demonstration on how to trace down problems by not spoiling OP with obvious answers.